# jQuery Mega Menu Flicker Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, megamenu

I wonder if anyone might be able to shed some light on a problem I'm having...

I have used a jQuery Mega Menu script for the below website:

http://www.furnituremind.co.uk/

I found the script from the below site:

http://designchemical.com/lab/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-plugin/examples/

The problem is that on loading, I can see the text flash quickly in an unformatted fashion as shown in the below picture:

http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/4421/screenshot20111221at193.png

Im looking for a way to fix this, but am unsure where to start. I've checked around the developers site, comments and Google but can't find a solution. Im thinking maybe there's a to place it in a temporarily hidden Div until the script is loaded.

Help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think that problem is caused because the html loads up and then the jquery plugin gets run. I seen this happen on u.i tabs and jquery form wizard(like: http://thecodemine.org/).

I don't think you can get jquery to bind any faster than document ready. The one thing I suggest is hide those sub menus by using css (display: none;) that way they will be hidden and you won't see them flash.

Comment: I've tried to add this in but I cant get them to display again when the javascript is run.

I've looked into changing the CSS value from hidden on page load but am struggling with the scripting. Not great with javascript.

Comment: you would have to post the js up and maybe we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

chobo2 is correct.

You can use the mega menus classes that are added when the menu is initialised to then unhide them after the menu has formed:

## main-mega li ul, #nav-main-mega .sub {display: none;}

## main-mega .sub ul {display: block;}

Comment: This css is already included in the mega-menu css as it comes now. Unfortunately, it does not remove the flicker. My menu still renders as a huge block of items visibly before it shrinks back up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to hide the sub-menus prior to loading:

```
#menu li ul {display: none;}
#menu .sub ul {display: block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same issue. I got the menu to stop the flicker by adding this as the first line of any CSS regarding the mega menu:

```
.megamenu li > div {display: none}
```

Comment: This removes the flicker, but then none of the drop down items show. Doesn't fully solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this as the first line to the CSS file you are using for the mega menu:

```
.mega-menu li > div {display: none}
```

Then add some jQuery to show that item again on doc ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mega-menu li > div').css('display', 'block');
});
```

This will remove the flicker.
I tried every soltion here none worked 100% for me. This does in IE11.

Answer (score -1):

At the First Line of Menu CSS you have to use following lines:-

```
#menu li ul {display: none;}
#menu .sub ul {display: block;}
```

Comment: these lines are already included in the css and they do not solve this issue.